# Set contains a proper infinite subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider that we define an "infinite" set as one which contains some proper subset that is in bijection with itself. Now suppose that $B$ is a set and $A \subset B$ is an infinite proper subset of $B$. Can we prove using just that definition and elementary facts about functions that $B$ must also be infinite?

Comment: I suppose you forgot the condition that $A$ be infinite. Then yes, let $f \colon A \to C$ a bijection with $C \subsetneq A$, extend it to $g \colon B \to (B\setminus A) \cup C$ by the identity on $B \setminus A$.

Comment: So far I'm the only person who's up-voted this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assuming $A$ to be infinite according to your definition, right?

Let $C$ be a proper subset, and $f : A \to C$ a bijection.

Consider the proper subset of $B$ given by $D = C \cup (B \setminus A)$.

Now consider the bijection $g : B \to D$ which is the identity on $B \setminus A$, and $f$ when restricted to $A$.

Comment: Great, thanks. I was thinking, does this argument holds if we take a concrete category, an object and a subobject and define the object to be infinite if there is an isomorphic proper subobject? So that you have this sort of "transitivity" even when keeping track of structure?

Comment: Surely some more considerations would have to be made, but still, is it possible to adapt this argument for this more general case? It seems it won't work directly even for groups.

Comment: Of course this notion of categoric infinity will differ from the notion of underlying-set-inifinity. For exmaple in the category of rings (with $1$), $\mathbb Z$ has no proper subobject, hence is not infinite using this definition.

Comment: It surely will, but will you still have this sort of "transitivity" of the infinity property?

Comment: I guess it's just wishful thinking, it does not work for groups (in this sense, $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is infinite, while $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ is not, although the first one is a proper subobject of the second.

Answer (score 3):

If you are assuming that $A$ is infinite, then yes, we can. In that case, there is a bijective function $f:A\to C$ with $C\subsetneq A$. Let $g$ be the identity function on $B\setminus A$. Then $f\cup g$ is a bijection between $B$ and a proper subset of itself, namely $(B\setminus A)\cup C=B\setminus (A\setminus C).$